# Safek echad baguf safek echad beta'arovet

Tags: halacha, safek, chiddush-talmudic-principle

What is safek beguf safek beta'arovet? Specifically, what is the the safek beguf? Also, How does it relate to safek sefeka?

Comment: You should give the source for the quote that you are asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concise explanation is brought in Halachapedia [here](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Klalei_Halacha):

> If there is a safek safeka that is built of one safek about the status of the item in question and one safek since it was lost in a mixture, many rishonim consider this an invalid safek safeka. Others consider an acceptable safek safeka. One example is a safek teref piece of meat that was mixed up with other pieces of kosher meat (when [bitul](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Nullification) wasn't relevant).<sup>1</sup> **The halacha holds that it is an invalid safek safeka**.<sup>2</sup>
>
> If it is a safek safeka with one safek that is about the status of the item potentially a dvar sheyesh lo matirin and one safek of the tarovet it is an invalid safek safeka.<sup>3</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> [Tosfot Beitzah 3b s.v. vacherot](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.3b.13?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Beitzah.3b.13.1&lang2=bi) writes that Rabbenu Tam considers a safek safeka even if one safek is about the status of an item and one safek is about a tarovet. This is also the opinion of Tosfot Zevachim 71a and Riva in Shitah Mikubeset Zevachim 74a. However, the Ri cited by Tosfot disagrees that such a safek safeka is an invalid safek safeka. [Rashba Beitzah 3a s.v. nitarva](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashba_on_Beitzah.3b.3?lang=bi) explains the opinion of the Ri; since the first safek is about the status of an item we determine that we are strict since it is a safek deoritta lchumra. Then we consider the second safek however at that time there's only one other safek. Rashba responsa 401 agrees with Rabbenu Tam.
>
> <sup>2</sup>  [Shulchan Aruch YD 110:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.110.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) holds it is an invalid safek safeka. [Gra 110:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.110.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that most poskim assume that it is an invalid safek safeka.
>
> <sup>3</sup> [Shulchan Aruch 102:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.102.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). [Shach 102:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.102.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that everyone agrees for dvar sheyesh lo matirin one safek in the guf and one in the tarovet is forbidden.

Comment: You seem to say that rabainu tam says it is valid and the Ri disagrees that it is invalid. ??

Comment: I am just quoting from what I saw on Halachapedia.

Comment: However, the Ri cited by Tosfot disagrees that such a safek safeka is a ''''valid''''' safek safeka.